# How to schedule downtime of EC2 instances using python?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have been seeing different ways to schedule downtime on running ec2 instances, I want to do it with the help of python script. I am new to python, hence looking for appropriate way/steps to schedule a downtime.

For eg : I am looking for a script which stops the EC2 instances when not in used (say on weekends) and restart them back on Monday's.
I will add a cron job for that which is fine, but looking for a python script to stop/terminate instances and start them.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Are you asking about scheduling downtime of events? or ec2 downtime for maintenance?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi downtime of running EC2 instances when not in used ..

Comment: @grepe I want  to schedule a job (cron job at the end ) which calls the python script and stop the ec2 instances when not in used ( like on weekends ) and restart them back on Monday (for eg )

Comment: We don't entertain requests for resource recommendations like this, here.  You can write a script and we can certainly help you with your code if/when it doesn't work, but seeking a tool is a job for Google, or searching Github. What you are contemplating should be a trivial task. CloudWatch could fire a Lambda function on a schedule, to interact with the EC2 API and stop/start machines. Or just start, because machines can put themselves in the stop state with `sudo poweroff` via local cron. (EC2 sees this and stops the instance and billing). Or get reserved instances and pay less overall. :)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot he is not searching for a tool. he is asking how to write and run a small python script that can turn an EC2 instance off and on again and he doesn't know where to start. that is IMHO a valid SO question.

Comment: @grepe you may be right.  I was interpreting *"I am looking for a script"* as a search for a tool recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an IAM role that has sufficient permissions (i.e. can list EC2 instances, check their status, turn them on and off), then write a Lambda function and assign it the role you created, trigger it on schedule (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) and use boto3 calls to turn the instance on/off (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.start).